# wp_enqueue_style for plugin options page

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to add a stylesheet to the options page for my plugin - code looks like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-rps-paypal', 'rps_paypal_add_css' );

function rps_paypal_add_css() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'rps_paypal', plugins_url( '/rps_paypal/css/rps-paypal.css' ) );
}


add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rps_myplugin_add_page' );

function rps_myplugin_add_page() {
add_options_page(
    'My PayPal Plugin',
    'My PayPal Plugin',
    'manage_options',
    'rps-paypal',
    'rps_myplugin_option_page'
);
}
```

Can't figure out why it's not showing up...

Comment: admin_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the admin pages. Use [admin_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the call to add_options_page will return the string literal to use for your RSS, so it should look something like this:

```
$page = add_options_page( ... );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'rps_paypal_add_css' );
```

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: You're welcome Richard. What Rast said below is true as well, you shouldn't hard-code your plugin name during the call to `plugins_rss`.

Answer (score 1):

First I am not sure you get hook suffix right. It is return of `add_options_page()` function and from quick test should be something like `admin_page_rps-paypal` in your case. But really you should save that return in the variable and use that rather than hardcode it.

Second your `plugins_url()` usage is little off, your plugin's folder name is not guaranteed to be that. More robust to use it like:

```
plugins_url('/css/rps-paypal.css', __FILE__);
```

Comment: Hi Rarst, Thanks so much for this - this is my first attempt at writing a plugin so all advice is greatly appreciated! - R